# Sinatra APP running with foreman on raspberry not reachable in Home-Network

Tags: ruby, network-programming, sinatra, puma, foreman

I have a question. Maybe this is easy and i just dont come behind it. 
I wrote a little Sinatra (ruby) WebApp. It is running with a puma server and is started with foreman. I now started it on my Raspberry (Raspian stretch). This is working.

```
14:28:45 web.1  | started with pid 10847
14:28:52 web.1  | Puma starting in single mode...
14:28:52 web.1  | * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
14:28:52 web.1  | * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
14:28:52 web.1  | * Environment: development
14:28:52 web.1  | * Listening on tcp://localhost:10001
14:28:52 web.1  | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

I can access it locally on my raspberry.

```
curl localhost:10001
```

this is working.

But I also want to reach it with my PC (Home network). And this is not working. 
I can ping the raspberry successfully.

```
ping 192.XXX.XXX.XX
```

but when i ping the port it is running on, it is not working (also try that with my browser). I have a fritzbox.

```
ping 192.XXX.XXX.XX:10001
```

Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rackup -p 10001 -s puma
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong :-( .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default rackup binds to localhost.  You have to tell it to listen on 0.0.0.0

`rackup -p 10001 -o 0.0.0.0`

or

`rackup -p 10001 --host 0.0.0.0`

Related source here: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/server.rb#L56